# Why do you jbuttons only align right when i resize the jframe

Tags: java, swing, resize, jbutton, grid-layout

I'm having a problem with jbuttons inside a jlabel on the jframe.

I'm attempting to make a minesweeper-like game where i will need lots of jbuttons - in this case there's 225, i have the buttons setup in a string and are added with a for & if statement.  The problem is that when i compile the program and run it, initially the jbuttons are not aligned properly, but when i resize the jframe with my mouse in either direction just slightly the buttons suddenly align.

**Before resizing**

[image]

**After resizing**

[image]

```
public class Minesweeper {

    public final void initUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Minesweeper");
        frame.setSize(320, 300);
        frame.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1, 0, 0));
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(15, 15, 0, 0));
        frame.add(panel);    
        String[] buttons = {
            "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",
            "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",
            "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",
            "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",
            "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",
            "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",
            "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",
            "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",
            "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
            "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",
            "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",
            "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",
            "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",
            "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",
            "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",
            "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",
            "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",
            "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",
            "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
            "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",
            "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",
            "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
            "", "", "", "", "", 
        };    

        for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length;) {    
            if (i < buttons.length) {
                panel.add(new JButton(buttons[i]));
                i++;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Unknown error 100");
            }
        }
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
         Minesweeper ex = new Minesweeper();
         ex.initUI();                
    }
}
```

Comment: After you have built the UI, pack the frame and THEN make it visible...

Comment: I'm an idiot, thanks didn't even notice i did that